# Make C-M-RET insert \item[]

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, auctex

In AUCTeX <kbd>M-RET</kbd> is bound to `(LaTeX-insert-item)` which makes a new properly indented line and inserts `\item` and a space after which the cursor is placed. I would like to extend this feature so that <kbd>C-M-RET</kbd> has similar functionality but for `\item[description]`.

What I would like is for <kbd>C-M-RET</kbd> to

1. make a new properly indented line and insert `\item[]`,
2. place the cursor between the square brackets, and
3. place the cursor one space after `\item[]` as <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: Auctex knows when you're in a description environment, and modifies the behaviour of `M-RET` automatically. Is this not working of you, or are you using \item[description] in some other context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function is cribbed from latex.el, and modified slightly to call the argument-prompting version `LaTeX-item-argument` instead of just inserting the item directly.

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-insert-item-arg ()
  "Insert a new item in an environment, prompting for an item label.
You may use `LaTeX-item-list' to change the routines used to insert the item."
  (interactive "*")
  (let ((environment (LaTeX-current-environment)))
    (when (and (TeX-active-mark)
           (> (point) (mark)))
      (exchange-point-and-mark))
    (unless (bolp) (LaTeX-newline))
    (if (assoc environment LaTeX-item-list)
    (funcall (cdr (assoc environment LaTeX-item-list)))
      (LaTeX-item-argument)) ;; ONLY THIS LINE IS DIFFERENT
    (indent-according-to-mode)))
```

You can bind that function to any key you like:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () 
    (local-set-key [(control return)] 'LaTeX-insert-item-arg)))
```

If you want `M-C-RET`, use `(meta control return)` instead, though it only seems to work with the `Alt` key, and not the `Esc` key (which usually behaves the same...)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want Textmate snippets behavior.

You need [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) to do the snippet expansion/field movement.  IMO, it's not a good solution to bind this to a key because the number of keys is limited, but yasnippet does allow you to do that as well.

Comment: `(LaTeX-insert-item)` is aware of LaTeX environments so that it indents properly. That's why I want similar functionality but for `\item[]`. I don't know how to make yasnippet aware of LaTeX environemnts. Also, `C-M-RET` and `C-RET` are not bound in AUCTeX.

Comment: I don't work with LaTeX, but yasnippet is able to indent snippets in major-modes where indentation is well defined, i.e. TAB indents correctly.  If you want the nice smooth field filling experience, I would look to yasnippet as a starting point.